# FuelPHP Request クラスでレスポンスヘッダを取得したい

Tags: php, fuelphp

[Laravel の throttle を引き上げたのに 429 がでる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57499/laravel-%e3%81%ae-throttle-%e3%82%92%e5%bc%95%e3%81%8d%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%92%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab-429-%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%82%8b)

こちらの質問に関連してなのですが
FuelPHP のAPIサーバーで Laravel のAPIサーバーからのレスポンスの
ヘッダ情報を取得するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか

該当のコードは以下のようになっていて

```
      $request = Request::forge($url, 'curl');
      $request->set_method('GET');
      $request->set_header('Accept','application/json');
      $result   = $request->execute();
      $response = $result->response();
```

この後ろに

```
      Log::debug(print_r($request->get_headers(), true));
      Log::debug(print_r($response->headers, true));
```

というのをはさんでみたんですが

```
DEBUG - 2019-08-27 06:14:37 --> Array
(
)

DEBUG - 2019-08-27 06:14:37 --> Array
(
)
```

というのが出力されただけで中身が入っていません

curl -v で該当サーバーになげると

```
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 4000
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 3999
```

というのがヘッダに入ってくるのでこれを取得したいのですが
なるべく動作してる部分は変更したくないので
Fuel Request からヘッダ内容を取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.curl-setopt.php

Fuel::Request の中で curl ライブラリを読んでるみたいで

```
set_option(CURLOPT_HEADER, true)
```

という curl にわたすオプションを追加したところ

```
$response->headers
```

の方に中身が入るようになり header 情報が取得できるようになりました